# How to account for 31 days using SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to generate rolling data for month. However, I am having an issue where the query doesnt generate any data when the month has 31 days.

I am defining my days here:

```
declare @today datetime
set @today = getdate()
declare @enddate datetime
set @enddate = @today
declare @begindate datetime
set @begindate = dateadd(mm, datediff(m,0,@today),0)
```

Then I am calling the days in my query using:

```
PURCHDATE BETWEEN @begindate AND @enddate
```

I can see my issue where my begin date is first day of the month and end date is today. How can I make this work for 31 day months?

Comment: I don't see the problem. `SELECT dateadd(mm, datediff(m,0,'2019-10-31'),0);` returns the 1st of october as expected...

Comment: Not an answer, but [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with 31 day months. You're calculating the dates for the beginning of the current month until today. If today is the first of the month (and it is), then those two are the same date. What's the issue? The results you're getting and the results you're expecting would go a long way toward helping us help you here.

Comment: You are right @EricBrandt. I am seeing this issue every month. Perhaps an issue with my logic. Let me see if I Close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
PURCHDATE >= CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate())) AND
PURCHDATE < CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(getdate())))
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of each CONVERT function. I tried to edit your answer, but I was prevented from doing so since my edit was less than 6 characters.

Comment: @Isaac, I have done that on Gordon's behalf. He is missing so many things today. Seems a bad day for him.

Comment: This suggestion also returns 0 rows.

Comment: Do you have any records with a PURCHDATE in August yet?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
 WHERE YEAR(PURCHDATE) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(PURCHDATE) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```